# How to call other EFL app from your EFL app in Tizen

Tags: tizen, efl

I'm preparing an app which needs to call the dialer app.
How do I go about calling the Dialer app from my app.

My app is being written in EFL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working with EFL apps in Tizen, use the following:

```
service_h service;
service_create(&service);
service_set_package(service, "com.service.call");
service_set_operation(service, "http://tizen.org/appcontrol/operation/main");
service_add_extra_data (service, "launch-type", "MO"); Addtional Data as with Intents
service_send_launch_request(service, NULL,NULL );
service_destroy(service);
```

This and in your application manifest, add

```
<permit>
    <smack permit="com.samsung.w-launcher-app" type="rw"/>
</permit>
```

and in your application xml, use this:

```
<privileges>
    <privilege>http://tizen.org/privilege/application.launch</privilege>
</privileges>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is AppControl native API, take a look at this example:
https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.0/org.tizen.native.apireference/classTizen_1_1App_1_1AppControl.html

```
using namespace Tizen::App;

void
MyAppClass::AppControlDialSample(void)
{

    String telUri = L"tel:12345678900";

    AppControl* pAc = AppManager::FindAppControlN(L"tizen.phone", L"http://tizen.org/appcontrol/operation/dial");
    if(pAc) 
    {
        pAc->Start(&telUri, null, null, null);
        delete pAc;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats for the Native Apps, I've resolved it for EFL ones